# Shopping cart-SEO-HTML Validates

Tags: seo, shopping-cart

Google is carefully tracking load time. Most carts I see fail miserably here.

Does anybody know of a shopping cart that follows W3C rules so it will validate? Or at least come close? So many are a disaster in the validator. 
Also will display a user edited Title tag, Desc tag and have a good URL? 
Am I dreaming if I want a cart that does not rewrite the URL?

Once I find a good cart, then I will chose a CMS system that will work with it. Or even HTML. I don't care. I just want a cart that works for SEO!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/features). It's not perfect, of course, but it does many of the things you're looking for.

Incidentally, HTML validation isn't a factor for SEO. Load time is, but it's only one of over 200 factors. Both are good things, but they need to be put in perspective.

Comment: HTML validation _is_ a factor. If a search engine can't extract a semantic outline of any document (cart or not), it's not going to be ranked as highly as it would be otherwise. Pages don't have to be perfect, but SE's do need to be able to determine what, if any main idea a page has beyond the title and tags.

Comment: @Tim - I'd refer you to this video by Matt Cutts from Google: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBACTS-tyg (starting around the 1:19 mark) It's not necessary for and gives no benefit to SEO, but it's still a good idea/goal for other purposes.

Comment: Good video! still, if your h1 or head tag is not closed you are going to have problems with spiders. Validation helps, and so it is a factor. I think Matt was saying, validated pages don't get "extra" points. But, they do boost your pages rank via other ranking factors. Basically there is no special boost for W3C valid pages, but they get the natural boost for being "accessible" because they are more "findable".